# Cannot build cc-tools with Boost 1.76 on macOS got 'cannot find the flags to link with Boost regex' error

Tags: c++, boost, build

I'm trying to build cc-tool debugger as described here https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/information/flashing_the_cc2531.html

But at configure step got this error

```
checking for the Boost regex library... no
configure: error: cannot find the flags to link with Boost regex
```

Same issue described here https://github.com/dashesy/cc-tool/issues/25 and suggested solution is to downgrade boost to 1.60. But it does not work anymore because 1.60 deleted from brew.

I've tried to use clang compiler instead of gcc but it does not work too.

MacOS: Big sur 11.5.2 (20G95)

Answer (score 24):

Here the solution:

```
CC=/usr/bin/clang \
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ \
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include \
LDFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include \
 ./bootstrap

CC=/usr/bin/clang \
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ \
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include \
CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x" \
LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -lboost_system" \
LIBUSB_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0 \
LIBUSB_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0" \
 ./configure
```

It allows to configure with boost 1.76. Found here https://gist.github.com/kidpixo/ef1a26ae953e3939a4eebe1b6fd2f07c

Answer (score 4):

For mac with M1 CPU, macOS Monterey (boost version 1.78.0):

```
CC=/usr/bin/clang \                          
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ \
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include \
LDFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include \
 ./bootstrap

CC=/usr/bin/clang \
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ \
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include \
CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x" \
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.78.0_1/lib/" \
LIBUSB_CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include/libusb-1.0 \
LIBUSB_LIBS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lusb-1.0" \
 ./configure
```

Comment: Thank you, tried a lot of things... this worked!

Comment: This also worked for me, after adjusting the path to my boost install

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the very same issue, right today (same OS: MacOS 11.5.2).

I think one solution would be to create your own tap, with the Formula copied from the removed boost@1.60 (Homebrew/homebrew-core#84434).